# Why doesn't scroll bar change when different values are chosen in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div and inside this div is a radio button group called color.  When a user selects a particular color, the background changes to the color chosen.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blue"><label for="blue">Blue</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" id="red"><label for="red">Red</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" id="green"><label for="green">Green</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange" id="orange"><label for="orange">Orange</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellow"><label for="yellow">Yellow</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="pink" id="pink"><label for="pink">Pink</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="gray" id="gray"><label for="gray">Gray</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="magenta" id="magenta"><label for="magenta">Magenta</label<br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="teal" id="teal"><label for="teal">Teal</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="color_selected"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="color"]').change(function() {
        var prevColor = $('#color_selected').val();
        if (prevColor) {
            $('#' + prevColor).next('label').css({'background':'#FFFFFF'});
        }
        var color = jQuery(this).val();
        $(this).next('label').css({'background':color});
        $('#color_selected').val(color);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nkqLj/2/)

This div also has a set width and height.  I have set overflow to scroll so all colors can be seen.  My problem is with the scroll, in that it doesn't work when arrow keys are used to select colors.

If any color after "Yellow" is selected, the div doesn't scroll down.  Is there a way for the scroll to follow the color that's selected?

Comment: That almost looks like a bug to me... when an element gains focus, it's supposed to be scrolled into view. Using the arrow keys cause focus to go from one radio button to the next, once it goes to pink it should scroll pink into view. manually focusing the pink radio button with code does correctly scroll it into view.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for that, [scrollIntoview()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView):

```
 $(this).next('label').css({'background':color}).get(0).scrollIntoView(false);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NbVpS/)

Answer (score 2):

I think the input elements are not scrolling automatically because they have `absolute` positioning.

You could scroll the elements yourself with a call to [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView).

```
$(this).next('label')[0].scrollIntoView();
```

But `scrollIntoView()` has its shorcomings. If you pass it `true` (the default), the elements will scroll so they align with the top. This might not work as you would like when you down arrow from the top element. If you pass it `false`, the elements will scroll so they align with the bottom. This might not work as you would like when you up arrow from the bottom element.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7hRe/1/)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - absolute positioning removes an element from the document's flow, so this certainly explains the "bug".

Comment: @Izkata - It works for me in Firefox and IE, but I just tried it in Chrome, and it doesn't work so well. I had tried to delete this answer before, but I was clearing out old answers earlier today and have apparently reached my limit of deletions for the day.

Answer (score 0):

use `scrollTop` method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="color"]').change(function() {
        var prevColor = $('#color_selected').val();
        if (prevColor) {
            $('#' + prevColor).next('label').css({'background':'#FFFFFF'});
        }
        var color = jQuery(this).val();
        $(this).next('label').css({'background':color});
        $('#color_selected').val(color);

        var xPosition = ($(this).index() /3)*15; 
        $("#scrolldiv").scrollTop(xPosition);

    });
});

<div id="scrolldiv">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blue"><label for="blue">Blue</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" id="red"><label for="red">Red</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" id="green"><label for="green">Green</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange" id="orange"><label for="orange">Orange</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellow"><label for="yellow">Yellow</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="pink" id="pink"><label for="pink">Pink</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="gray" id="gray"><label for="gray">Gray</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="magenta" id="magenta"><label for="magenta">Magenta</label<br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="teal" id="teal"><label for="teal">Teal</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="color_selected"/>
</div>
```

[**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bM96Y/)